# How to using a Class in input of Room Query

Tags: java, kotlin, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-mvvm

I try to use a query in room dao:

```
 @Query("Select * FROM tbl_generalItems WHERE ShowType IN (:query.Types) ORDER BY :query.OrderBy DESC LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset ")
    DataSource.Factory<Integer, GeneralItemModel> getLazyPage(int limit, int offset,SeeAllQuery query);
```

but I can't using SeeAllQuery .class in my query input and my `SeeAllQuery.class` is:

```
public class SeeAllQuery {

    private LinkedList<Integer> Types;
    private String Query;
    private String OrderBy;
    private String Filter;

    public SeeAllQuery(String Query,
                       String OrderBy,
                       String Filter) {

        Types = new LinkedList<>();
        this.Query = Query;
        this.OrderBy = OrderBy;
        this.Filter = Filter;
    }
```

Is there a solution to using this class in input of my `DAO` Query method?